# Grails Paypal plugin with Netbeans

Tags: grails, netbeans

I downloaded and installed the paypal plugin http://www.grails.org/PayPal+Plugin using netbeans. Though the website mentioned there will be a controller and domain class created. However, I don't see it. Can someone advice if I installed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The Controller and domain class are located within the plugin itself. Browse the source of the plugin to see them.

Comment: I am not familiar with NetBeans but in Spring Source Tool Suite (STS) you can view the Grails Dependancies (which include plugins) and drill down to the resources within them. Alternatively you can look at the plugin source from the file system (~/.grails/<grails version>/projects/<project>/plugins)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is probably located in a hidden directory under your profile. Not the Netbeans project folder. For instance on grails 2.0 on Linux:
/home/user/.grails/2.0.0.M2/projects/testapp/plugins/paypal-0.6.4.
Each plugin is like a complete project with directory structure.
Your project has use of the plugin when it's installed, and includes it when you build it.